# GWT simple web form submit - redirect to new page

Tags: java, gwt

I have a simple web form written in Google web toolkit. I want the user to follow a new URL when he clicks on the submit button. However I cannot find any examples of redirecting the user to a new URL from within GWT code. How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To redirect the user to a new page, use [`Window.Location.assign()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#assign(java.lang.String)).

To have this happen when the user submits the form, use [`FormPanel.addSubmitHandler()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#addSubmitHandler(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel.SubmitHandler)) , or `addSubmitCompleteHandler()` to have the redirect happen when the form submission is complete.

Answer (score 7):

the exact answer is:

```
    form.getElement().<FormElement>cast().setTarget("");
```

by this line you changing the target parameter of the form and now the main page redirected to the action url.

be careful that  Window.Location.assign() makes a new GET request after your main POST request!, So it is not the answer.

Comment: I had no clue why my page redirect was being cancelled. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

So actually what you need to do is to use the *setAction()* method of the FormPanel AND you need to construct the form panel as such:

> FormPanel form = new FormPanel(new
>   NamedFrame("_self"));

This will make the submit redirect as usual.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at example at roughain http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~FormPanel

Also you can read javadoc @http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html

To make user go to a url use `setAction` method of FormPanel