# How to render return HTML content after GWT form submit successfully

Tags: gwt, form-submit, formpanel

I want to mimic the traditional form submit in GWT via `FormPanel`, but the page can't redirect to the action Servlet in one HTTP trip, that is , submit is one trip, if you `window.location.assign` makes another. Even though I can have the result html via `submitCompleteEvent.getResult` which could not be rendered properly.
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062104/gwt-simple-web-form-submit-redirect-to-new-page) does not help me out.

So I split this question:

***1.*** Can I really mimic HTML Form behavior by GWT FormPanel, which triggers the go-to action page on submit ?

***2.*** How can I utilize the returning html from form successful submit ?

Comment: Well, the key to this question is the form 'target' attibute，once I changed the target to '_blank', it appears like a normal form.
The form submit result can also be rendered,if you find the right place to render it .